# SVG - Line at baseline

Tags: svg, line, baseline

I am drawing something here as you can see.

But there is a problem: the lines at the very top and very bottom of the image (the black `"ruler"`) are only half the width because the `"base"` of the line is in the center.

For a text field, I was able to reposition the `dominant-baseline` and thus position my texts perfectly. However, a line (or path) doesn't seem to have a baseline.

How can I make sure my lines are at the very top and very bottom? Is the only way to do this to hard position them at the `line width / 2`? I tested this out, and it works perfectly, however, I'm not the biggest fan of hard coding these numbers. Is there a way not to hard code this?

Here's my code and my example image:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);"/>
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 127, 0);"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="20%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  <line x1="22%" x2="22%" y1="0%" y2="100%" style="stroke: black;"/>
  <line x1="22%" x2="24.5%" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: black;"/>
  <line x1="22%" x2="24.5%" y1="50%" y2="50%" style="stroke: black;"/>
  <line x1="22%" x2="24.5%" y1="100%" y2="100%" style="stroke: black;"/>
  <text x="25%" y="0%" dominant-baseline="hanging">Top text</text>
  <text x="25%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <tspan x="25%" dy="-3%">middle text 1</tspan>
    <tspan x="25%" dy="6%">middle text 2</tspan>
  </text>
  <text x="25%" y="100%">bottom text</text>
</svg>
```

Here's a Fiddle if you want to try it out. Just zoom in really far.
https://jsfiddle.net/jkom2x8f/1/
[image: Look at the 2 small lines (1 on the top and 1 on the bottom.]

Comment: I made same minor changes to wording, to make your question more clear/readable.

Comment: To be clear, I was able to solve it by doing the `line width / 2` trick, but it doesn't look nice...

Comment: Don't put such information into comments, always update your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the correct solution.  It is the only real solution.  There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It seems indeed that this is the only possible way... I don't like it, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after a lot of searching around and reading the comments, I concluded that hard coding the y positions to 0.5 and 199.5 is the only way to do it:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);"/>
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 127, 0);"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="20%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    <line x1="22%" x2="22%" y1="0%" y2="100%" style="stroke: black;"/>
    <line x1="22%" x2="24.5%" y1="0.5" y2="0.5" style="stroke: black;"/>
    <line x1="22%" x2="24.5%" y1="50%" y2="50%" style="stroke: black;"/>
    <line x1="22%" x2="24.5%" y1="199.5" y2="199.5" style="stroke: black;"/>
    <text x="25%" y="0%" dominant-baseline="hanging">Top text</text>
    <text x="25%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle">
        <tspan x="25%" dy="-3%">middle text 1</tspan>
        <tspan x="25%" dy="6%">middle text 2</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="25%" y="100%">bottom text</text>
</svg>
```

Here's a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jkom2x8f/5/